# Is usage of console.log/console.error in production code considered as bad/good practice?

Tags: bestpractice

Well I've seen a lot of code examples provided by Salesforce. In one blog post - [Error Handling Best Practices for Lightning and Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html) - they are using `console.error` to report errors on ui. They also mentioned:

> Reporting the error in the console is a start

But I was told that leaving `console` outputs in production code is not a good practice. Could anybody explain what is the best practice then?

This is not a duplicate of [How to handle errors for Apex in lighting components?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270341/how-to-handle-errors-for-apex-in-lighting-components), but a different question.